Extract Data from an API and load it in to snowflake as table and finally connect those tables to power bi for visualiztion
I want to use this api documentation from this link https://api.sproutsocial.com/docs/
I want to store that data as snwoflake table
Step1: I was able to extract data for all the profiles in the url i.e historical data and I loaded to snowflae
Limitation1: to get latest data for yesterday and today and day befor you have wait for three consecutive days so that is why for daily run I fetch’s data for rolling one week
Limatiotn2 as I fetch data for rolling one week some of the columns might not for that date range that is why I am not able to append that weekly to the historical table in snowflakes
Not sure how to deal with this I useETl approach I transform data in pandas
Thanks in advance
I have written the code that fetches the historical data without any errors and I am not scale the solution to for daily runs
